# Disabling all child views inside the layout

Tags: java, android, childviews

I saw many threads related to this, before posting my question. But none worked for me. I have a RelativeLayout with many other layouts and fragments as children. I want to disable all the children of "content_view" as well as the content_view itself on a button click. I tried

```
contentView.setDisabled(false);
```

This didn't work. I've also tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
    child.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Even this didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Please find my .xml code below.
I even tried placing a view above all views. Even that didn't solve my problem.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/channel_actionbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/body_container"
            android:layout_below="@+id/channel_actionbar"
            android:duplicateParentState="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/channelList"
                android:duplicateParentState="true">

                <com.mobile.subview.ScrollViewWithScrollListener
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:duplicateParentState="true">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:duplicateParentState="true">

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/imagePlaceHolder"
                            android:duplicateParentState="true"></FrameLayout>

                        <TableLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/channelTable"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imagePlaceHolder"
                            android:duplicateParentState="true"></TableLayout>

                        <com.mobile.subview.CustomTextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="You do not qualify for any engagements or channels.  Please check back later."
                            app:typeface="fonts/HelveticaNeue"
                            app:customStyle="Regular"
                            android:id="@+id/noChannelsMessage"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/contentTextSize"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </com.mobile.subview.ScrollViewWithScrollListener>

                <com.mobile.subview.ParallaxImage
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/channel_actionbar"
                android:id="@+id/sibling_view"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"></RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/retailersContainer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/channel_actionbar">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.mobile.subview.List"
            android:id="@+id/retailers"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/retailers"
            android:id="@+id/retailerClickBlocker"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"></FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/channel_actionbar"
        android:background="#F8F8F8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/shared_navmenu_button"
            android:id="@+id/show_menu_button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginLeft='5px'
            android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

        <com.mobile.subview.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/channel_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/titleTextSize"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Test Title"
            app:typeface="fonts/HelveticaNeue"
            app:customStyle="Medium"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/shared_navbar_logo2x"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

        <com.mobile.subview.CustomButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/channel_done_btn"
            app:typeface="fonts/HelveticaNeue"
            app:customStyle="Regular"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

        <com.mobile.subview.CustomButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:typeface="fonts/HelveticaNeue"
            app:customStyle="Regular"
            android:id="@+id/channel_share_btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#D6D6D6"
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/click_preventing_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#66000000"
        android:clickable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because your layouts are so heavily nested, you need to recursively disable the views. Instead of using your method, try something like this:

```
private static void disable(ViewGroup layout) {
    layout.setEnabled(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            disable((ViewGroup) child);
        } else {
            child.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

then call:

```
disable(content_view);
```

Comment: Im getting exception here...    thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4108b2a0)
11-05 17:46:09.354  19082-19082/air.com.test.mobile W/System.err﹕ java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-05 17:46:09.378  19082-19082/air.com.test.mobile W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:5673)

Comment: Why isn't android:duplicateParentState="true" not working while changing the parent's state?

Comment: It might work if you make all of your views have duplicateParentState, but it would have to go all the way down the hierarchy. I'm also not totally sure if duplicateParentState applies to the disabled state; it looks like it only applies to the visual styling of the elements, not their behavior.

Comment: This works as expected. But it is disabling other layouts outside content_view

Comment: No problem! If this worked, don't forget to accept the answer by hitting the green checkbox. Thanks!

Comment: This is causing a different problem. So I can't accept the answer. However I can up vote it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake. Its working fine now!! Accepting your answer

Answer (score 4):

Even though the answer is expected instead of using recursion I think the below code will do the trick.This is what I used to disbale it. I just passed parentlayout and whether to show or hide as a boolean parameter

```
private void disable(LinearLayout layout, boolean enable) {
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
            child.setEnabled(enable);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) child;
                for (int j = 0; j < group.getChildCount(); j++) {
                    group.getChildAt(j).setEnabled(enable);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are Kotlin versions:

**Using [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx)**

```
fun View.changeEnableChildren(enable: Boolean) {
    isEnabled = enable
    (this as? ViewGroup)?.let {
        forEach {
            changeEnableChildren(enable)
        }
    }
}
```

**Without [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx)**

```
fun View.changeEnableChildren(enable: Boolean) {
    isEnabled = enable
    (this as? ViewGroup)?.let {
        for (i in 0..it.childCount) {
            changeEnableChildren(enable)
        }           
    }
}
```

**Note: recursive method may cause [StackOverFlowError](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StackOverflowError)** in that case you should replace `changeEnableChildren(enable)` with `isEnabled=enable`

Answer (score 0):

apply `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to the children

Comment: This is a good solution, but some widgets ignore it, for example spinner for disable.