# clear all child of a view (RadioGroup)

Tags: android, checkbox, view

I have a drawer menu with a dynamic option inside it and I got to fill it.
I want to clear all the child of a `RadioGroup` inside `adapter` but I didn't find anything.

p.s: I fill all `RadioGroup` with `addView` and fill it with `CheckBox`

ps2: The question is not about the check and uncheck. I want to find out how can remove all child of a view (like `RadioGroup`).

```
viewHolder.mRadioGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
/////clear viewHolder.mRadioGroup child hear, befor add new child to it
for (int i; i<10; i++) {
   RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mContext);
   radioButton.setText(selectableValue.getValue());
   viewHolder.mRadioGroup.addView(radioButton);
}
```

Comment: radioGroup.clearCheck();

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar i want to clear child, not clear check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This :

```
    int count = radioGroup.getChildCount();
    if(count>0) {
       for (int i=count-1;i>=0;i--) {
           View o = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
           if (o instanceof RadioButton) {
               radioGroup.removeViewAt(i);
           } 
       } 
    }
```

Comment: @Ashkan If you want to remove all view then remove **if (o instanceof RadioButton)** line from code

Comment: nope, the item is more than this. and I have not access to do this at that moment.

Comment: I cannot understand you. what you want to do exactly.please re edit question.to make more clear

Comment: explain about **if(o instanceof RadioButton) ** plz

Comment: it will check if child view RadioButton then only it removes.if you remove then it will remove all childs inside.

Comment: I found something interesting today going to add as another answer please take look

Comment: it has a problem, but tanx for your time. i live the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This taken from link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800422/disabling-all-child-views-inside-the-layout) for complex nested layout

```
private static void disable(ViewGroup layout) {
    layout.setEnabled(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            disable((ViewGroup) child);
        } else { 
            child.setEnabled(false);
        } 
    } 
}
```